# input type="submit" как сделать всегда активной

Tags: php

как сделать input type="submit" включалась автоматически

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="?step=3">
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="2" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="type_payment" value="<?=$type_payment?>">
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"style= "background-color: green; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 21px;" value="Включить <?=$koshel[$type_payment]?> руб." />
</form>
```

Comment: куда включалась?

Comment: При открытии страницы включалась автоматически

Comment: Что значит включалась? Она всегда включена

Comment: Нет, форма запускается при нажатии кнопки ,,Включить,. а нужно что бы форма запускалась автоматически

Comment: Так всё же submit включить или форму запустить? Определитесь пожалуйста......А что значит "форма запускалась автоматически" ?  Автоматически когда? При загрузки страницы?

Comment: Да при загрузке страницы, с помощью JavaScript ( <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="?step=3">
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="2" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="type_payment" value="<?=$type_payment?>">
<button type="submit" onClick="placeOrder(this.form)">Place Order</button>
</form>
<script>
function placeOrder(form){
    form.submit();
}
</script>)

Comment: а что сейчас не так?........а вы понимаете, что у вас будет бесконечный цикл? страница загружается - автоматом на ту же страницу сабмитит - опять загружается страница - опять на ту же страницу и т.д.

Comment: Нет Алексей здесь так не будет, таким образом хочу укоротить процес.